# Deploy django app on Windows Server

Tags: django, windows-server

I need help in deploying my django app on Windows Server.
I have tried virtualizing a server but i did not succeed.
Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: have you tried this: http://www.toptal.com/django/installing-django-on-iis-a-step-by-step-tutorial

Comment: Thanks a lot @Damien...let me check it out!